# How to count characters in a textarea containing tags

Tags: jquery, tags, character, counter

I want to be able to count the number of characters in a textarea, and report out to the customer when they have run out of chracters. I have done that just fine, but now I need to add some more functionallity and I am lost where to start.

Basically along with normal characters the customer will be able to add tags to the textbox from a button (this is already done). The tagg is inserted into the content in the following format:

some random content [tag] with more content

I want to be able to measure the number of characters and wherever a [tag] occurs add 20 characters to the total. It also nneds to remove the additional characters when a [tag] or part of a [tag] is deleted.

I have a basic version working, but it can't figure when a tag is deleted.

```
function countCharacters(totalTags){

    var new_length = $('#t_text').val().length;
    if (new_length < 10){
        totalTags=0;    
    }
    additionalcharacters = totalTags*10;
    var new_length = $("#t_text").val().length+additionalcharacters;
    if(new_length <= 154) {
        $('#charlimitinfo').removeClass('red');
        $('.cost').html('1');
    } else if(new_length >= 154 && new_length <= 308) {
        $('#charlimitinfo').removeClass('red');
        $('.cost').html('2');
    } else if(new_length >= 308 && new_length <= 462) {
        $('#charlimitinfo').removeClass('red');
        $('.cost').html('3');
    } else if(new_length >= 462 && new_length <= 606) {
        $('#charlimitinfo').removeClass('red');
        $('.cost').html('4');
    } else if(new_length >= 606 && new_length <= 616) {
        $('#charlimitinfo').addClass('red');
        $('.cost').html('5');
    }         
    else {
        if(new_length >= 616){
            $('#t_text').next('#charlimitinfo').addClass('red');
            $('#charlimitinfo').html('You have reached 616 characters!');
            this.value = this.value.substring(0, 616);
            return false;
        }
        else{
            $('#charlimitinfo').removeClass('red');
            $('#charlimitinfo').html((616 - new_length) +'<span>characters left</span>');
            return true;
        }
    }
    $('#charlimitinfo').html(new_length);  
}
```

t_text = The textarea
totalTags = A counter for each time a tag button is clicked and a tag inserted.

Hope someone can help as this is kettling my swede.

Cheers

Dave

Comment: Question: Would something like the following be adequate to return all of the tags currently in the box?

    var tags = $("#t_text").val().match(/[[](\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)[]]/g);

If so, an approach is possible that would be consistent no matter how the user enters or deletes a tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question. I'd probably handle it with regular expressions, rather than with a tag counter:

```
function countCharacters()
{
    var text = $('#t_text').val(),
        tags = ['tag', 'tag2'], // An array of your tags
        i,
        matches,
        regex,
        extraCharacters = 0,
        totalCharacters;

    for (i = 0; i < tags.length; i++)
    {
        regex = new RegExp('\\[' + tags[i] + '\\]', 'g');
        matches = text.match(regex) || [];
        extraCharacters += (matches.length * 20) - (matches.length * (tags[i].length + 2));
    }

    totalCharacters = text.length + extraCharacters;

    // Do your if statements/style changes/etc. here
}
```

This makes a couple assumptions:

- Each tag is worth 20 characters (as mentioned in your post, though the code said 10)
- The tag is *replaced by* the 20 characters
- The tags are actually in your text (I don't see why they wouldn't be)

The big advantage to this solution is that if someone manually puts a tag in, this will catch it, whereas your tag counter would not.

**Edit**

The code is untested, and the regex may be greedy (matching the longest possible match first). Testing now.

**Edit 2**

Okay, something is terribly wrong with the code. Figuring out what it is.

**Edit 3**

Turns out you have to double-escape special characters when making a regex out of a string: `new RegExp('\\[' + tags[i] + '\\]', 'g')` - once for the string, and once for the regex. Also, `string.matches(regex)` returns null if no matches are found, so we'll OR it with an empty array, and use the length of `matches` in our calculation.

Man. I lose at coding. :-D

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for the post, that does seem a much better way of working this out. The problem with the code is that on the third character totalCharacters returns NaN. Not sure why, but looking at it now too.

Comment: The code has been fixed. There were a few different errors in it, as described by my third edit.